# Каким образом выдавать только необходимые подсказки при вводе

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Здравствуйте. В базе данных MySQL есть таблицы `street` и `houses`. В таблице **street** занесены улицы, а в таблице **houses** - номер дома. Эти таблицы взаимосвязаны. То есть, определенные дома, могут быть привязаны к определенной улице. 
Структура таблицы `houses` :

```
id - AUTO_INCREMENT
id_street - id улицы, к которой привязан дом
```

На сайте есть поля, input, при вводе символов в которые, появляются возможные варианты, на основе тех которые есть в базе данных.

Всего таких полей 2. Одно для ввода улицы, другое для ввода дома.

**Вопрос**: Каким образом сделать, чтобы при вводе дома, выдавало только те подсказки, которые привязаны к введенной улице (сразу пользователь должен ввести улицу) ?

Код который отвечает за вывод подсказок для улицы:

```
$sl1 = array();
$all_city_db1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `street`");
while ($city_name_ru1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_city_db1)) {
   $sl1[] = $city_name_ru1['name_ru']; //получаем из базы все улицы и забиваем их в массив
}


var availableTags1 = <?=json_encode($sl1); ?>;

var availableTagsUpperCase1 = availableTags1.map(function(value) {
  return value.toUpperCase();
});

$("#street").keyup(function(){
  checkTags();
});

$( "#street" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags1,
  close: function() {
    checkTags();
  } 
});


<input id="street" name="street" type="text">
```

Подсказки для дома вывожу таким же образом. Но как сделать чтобы из базы выбирались только те подсказки, которые привязаны к введенной улице, не могу придумать. 
По сути нужно определить когда был выход из поля для ввода улицы, и потом делать запрос в базу и делать выборку. Но как все это реализовать без перезагрузки страницы я не могу понять. 
P.S. У улицы поле и именем **name_ru** - уникальное.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: так как дом вводиться? например если номер дома то он будет на всех улицах.

Comment: @Naumov при добавление номера дома в базу, он привязывается к определенной улице. например *дом 10* . но у каждой записи уникален **id**

Comment: @Naumov я думал проверять поле улица на изменение, $( ".target" ).change(function() {
но если выбирать улицу из подсказок, которые всплывают при вводе, этот метод просто не срабатывает

Comment: `select * from houses where street_id = ?` ;)